# Where can I view sent Kaa notifications?

Tags: kaa

Is there a possibility to review the sent notifications?

And also an overview about which endpoints received the notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All about notification feature you can find in the [documentation](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Programming-guide/Key-platform-features/Notifications/).
There is no API to view sent notifications. You can try to realize some logic with confirmation response on endpoint side based on received notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So you are saying, that there is no overview about the endpoints inside the Kaa-API, and which of the endpoints have received the notification and which did not.
So a workaround would be to create an endpoint, which is linked to all other endpoints sending events instead of notifications?